# Split one row into multiple ones

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, split, row

I want to split one row of data into multiple ones, like this example below :
[image: Picture of my problem. I have a long row with 12 values, that I want to cut into 4 rows of 3 values each.]

I have a row with 12 values. I want to fill my table like you can see : 3 by row and so on.

I tried to put into cell A2 : =B7, and then drag it to the right.
It works. But I obviously cannot drag it vertically after that.
So my problem is to cut this line into multiple ones, or to know how I can drag a value/function horizontally AND vertically.

My researchs leads me to Kutools, but I cannot afford it and I'm convinced that it could be done without it, even without VBA I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using <kbd>WRAPROWS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=WRAPROWS(A7:L7,3)
```

---

Using `INDEX()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMN(A1)>3, "", INDEX($B$7:$M$7, , COLUMN(A1)+(ROW(A1)-1)*3)), "")
```

---

Comment: Looks like a great solution, but I only have Excel 2016 and this function seems to be released in 2022. Have you some other idea to do this in my past version ?

Comment: @MathB yes that is possible one moment please

Comment: @MathB try this formula : `=IFNA(IF(COLUMN(A1)>3, "", INDEX($B$7:$M$7, , COLUMN(A1)+(ROW(A1)-1)*3)), "")`